# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc dependency and ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

We have existing libraries that depend on MVC, for example to provide custom action filters. These libraries are published as Nuget.

Until now, we just referenced `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` from the library, so that we could use the respective types (such as `ActionFilterAttribute`). But starting with ASP.NET Core 3, Microsoft stopped publishing many Nuget packages as [indicated by the upgrade guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#remove-obsolete-package-references), among them `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`.

How should libraries that depend on MVC reference MVC, starting with ASP.NET Core 3?

Answer (score 3):

This is outlined in section [library multi-targeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#migrating-libraries-via-multi-targeting) in the upgrade guide:

The library must target both .NET Core 3 and .NET Standard 2.0, and use conditionals to either use a `PackageReference` or `FrameworkReference`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp3.0'">
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#opt-in-to-runtime-compilation

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation in the link you provided, you can either target the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK which will reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` shared framework implicitly:

> Projects that target the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK implicitly reference the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` framework.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
    ...
</Project>
```

Or explicitly for other SDKs:

> Projects that target `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` or `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` SDK, should add an explicit `FrameworkReference` to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
    ...
</Project>
```

Are there certain libraries that you depended on that aren't included in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` shared framework?